# Does the BotFramework-WebChat require a bot service?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-cognitive-services, openai-api

I would like to use this framework as the UI component for any API service.
According to the documentation it seems the bot framework is a requirement (see screenshot).

Question: Is this indeed a requirement, or is it open to using any backend service (for the chat conversation)?

[image]

Comment: Accepting / upvoting an answer serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" and upvote it. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, BotFramework-WebChat requires you to use the DirectLine service that is provided by Azure for communicating with a BotFramework bot. As such, WebChat is heavily dependent on the BotFramework-DirectLineJS library, with extensive integrations throughout its code, in order to facilitate this happening.

It would be, by far, easier to design and build your own solution rather than to try and strip WebChat of its Directline integrations.

That being said, WebChat is a sophisticated application that does its job well. If you're capable enough to understand and follow the developer's code, you could use it as a reference to build your own client.

In the end, WebChat simply houses an adapter that connects to DirectLine to send and receive activities with a bot. Its sophistication comes in what it does with the activities.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it is possible to use Botframework-WebChat as UI component. However, it would require some effort to build an adapter which would interact with any messaging protocol.

We can see in the example that WebChat accepts a `directLine` property.

```js
<script>
  window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
        token: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_TOKEN'
      }),
      userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID',
      username: 'Web Chat User',
      locale: 'en-US'
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat')
  );
</script>
```

`window.WebChat.createDirectLine()` basically creates a DirectLine object that `WebChat` would interact with to send & receive messages.

You could create an adapter to mock the DirectLine object with the same interface for WebChat to interact with.

The DirectLine object interface looks like this:

```js
export interface IBotConnection {
    connectionStatus$: BehaviorSubject<ConnectionStatus>,
    activity$: Observable<Activity>,
    end(): void,
    referenceGrammarId?: string,
    postActivity(activity: Activity): Observable<string>,
    getSessionId? : () => Observable<string>
}
```

An `activity` is basically a message in DirectLine world. WebChat only understands `activity`. In order to connect to any backend, we need a "translator" (adapter) to convert messages back and forth.

An `activity$` is a `rxjs` observer which needs to be created to listen to the incoming messages from your backend, converted to `activity` for `WebChat` to understand, then "posts" it back to WebChat

`postActivity(activity)` is called when a message is sent by clicking on the send button of WebChat. The `activity` would have to be converted to the message of your backend, the send it to your service.

`this.connectionStatus$` is used to send the status to `WebChat`

References:

- https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/blob/master/src/directLine.ts
- https://github.com/compulim/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/bundle/src/createDirectLine.js